# present perfect tense in Japanese

Tags: grammar

How often does Japanese use present perfect tense?　My friend has been asking to watch a Japanese anime movie called 風たちぬ, this is the first time I have ever seen this 'nu' particle usage. Before I only have encountered the 'nu' as in 待たぬ for negative sentences. It seems the meaning of the title is 'The wind has risen'. Is it normal to say that in daily life? If not, what is the normal way to say it? would it be 風をもう立った？

Answer (score 1):

> How often does Japanese use present perfect tense?

There isn't a present perfect tense in Japanese (persay) [There is a discussion about it here](http://thejapanesepage.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13715)

> 待たぬ 
>   Is it normal to say that in daily life?

Not normal, sounds like old Japanese

> If not, what is the normal way to say it?

[風]{かぜ}が[出]{で}てきた

:-)

Comment: 風が出てきた is nice poetic use of the verb 出る. [風]{かぜ}が[吹]{ふ}き[始]{はじ}めた is a daily plain expression.